# Not updating view from Angularfire

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Lets try to make this as simple as possible. My view is not updating although changes are getting up to Firebase. I have tried to use callback functions here and there to no luck and it doesn't seem like they are needed here, but my view isn't updating until after the page refreshes. I am trying to implement a counter every time a button is clicked.

**View**

```
//The selected is just because I needed to select the key to show the correct
//values in the view
<div class="row"><div class="onehundred">{{hc.selected.counter}}</div>
<span class="onehundreddonuts"> donuts</span></div>
```

**Controller**

```
function incrementCounter() {
//I have tried wrapping this in a .then(function(){}) callback function based 
//on the self.player.$loaded() but this doesn't fix anything, so I took it out
//for simplicity. If I console.log my self.player = homeService.player array
//it prints it out correctly anyway.

homeService.incrementCounter();
}
```

**Service**

```
function incrementCounter() {
self.counter ++;
self.update();

}
function update() {
self.player.$save(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this can help in similar situations:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: One or the other should be enough btw. So either embed the code in `$timeout(){...}` or end it with `$scope.apply()`.